# Replace ' with \' in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

I'm trying to figure out how to replace a quote like `'` with something like `\'`.

How would I do this?

I have tried

```
"'".gsub("'","\\'")
```

but it just gives an empty string. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I hope your not trying to escape SQL input. Always 'prepare' your statements.

Comment: No, it is escaping code, but not SQL.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

How about this

```
puts "'".gsub("'","\\\\'")
\'
```

The reason is that `\'` means *post-match* in gsub (regex) and because of that it needs to be escaped with `\\'` and `\` is obviously escaped as `\\`, ending up with `\\\\'`.

Example

```
>> "abcd".gsub("a","\\'")
=> "bcdbcd"
```

`a` is replaced with everything after `a`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that for me.. I guess gsub just has some hidden "features"

Answer (score 3):

The `$'` variable is the string to the right of the match. In the `gsub` replacement string, the same variable would be `\'` -- hence the problem.

```
x = "'foo'"
x.gsub!(/'/, "\\'")
puts x.inspect        # foo'foo
```

This should work:

```
x = "'foo'"
x.gsub!(/'/, "\\\\'")
puts x.inspect
puts x
```

Answer (score 0):

That might be a bug.. Or at the very least, something which breaks MY idea of the principle of least surprise.

```
irb(main):039:0> "life's grand".gsub "'", "\\\'"
=> "lifes grands grand"
irb(main):040:0> "life's grand".gsub "'", "\\\\'"
=> "life\\'s grand"
```

Comment: Yes, this is not making sense to me.. sure I could use regex for it, but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

A two-step approach I've actually used...

```
BACKSLASH = 92.chr
temp = "'".gsub("'", "¤'")
puts temp.gsub("¤", BACKSLASH)
=> "\'"
```

Will only work if '¤' isn't used in the text obviously...

Answer (score -1):

How about doing this :

```
"'".gsub("\\","\\\\\\\\").gsub("'","\\\\'")
```

Not pretty but I think it works...

Comment: The destructive version doesn't work either. just gives back a blank string from the irb prompt

Comment: Ruby version is `ruby 1.8.6 (2009-06-08 patchlevel 369) [x86_64-openbsd4.6]`